# Choose a function from a tibble of function names, and pipe to it

Tags: r, magrittr

Let's say I have a tibble (or data frame, whatever) with a list of function names. Let's say, something like:

```
functions <- tibble(c("log()", "log10()", "sqrt()"))
```

I want to be able to pipe a data set to one of these functions, chosen by index. For example, I might want to do something like:

```
data %>% functions[[1]]
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I'm very new to pipes, but I am pretty sure this is easy, even if can't get it to work with !! etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
functions <- c("log", "log10", "sqrt")
```

there's no reason to put those in a tibble, and if you do you'll need `functions[[1]][1]` as @ Aaghaz-Hussain mentions.

```
seq(10) %>% get(functions[1])()
# [1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379 1.7917595 1.9459101 2.0794415 2.1972246 2.3025851
```

`get` will retrieve the function definition from its name as a string, after this it's a straightforward pipe, except you need to make sure the `()` are explicit as `seq(10) %>% get(functions[[1]])` it will be interpreted as `seq(10) %>% get(.,functions[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks so much, does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 6):

**1) match.fun** Use `match.fun` to turn a string into a function.  The dot, `.`, is optional.

```
functions <- c("log", "log10", "sqrt")
10 %>% match.fun(functions[2])(.)
## [1] 1
```

**1a)** This could also be written as:

```
10 %>% (match.fun(functions[2]))
## [1] 1
```

**1b)** or

```
10 %>% (functions[2] %>% match.fun)
## [1] 1
```

**2) do.call** `do.call` would also work:

```
10 %>% { do.call(functions[2], list(.)) }
## [1] 1
```

**3)** **call/eval** Generally `eval` is frowned upon but it does form another alternative:

```
10 %>% call(functions[2], .) %>% eval
## [1] 1
```

Comment: or `10 %>% eval(parse(text=functions[[2]]))()` if you really want to make people frown :).

Comment: So basically, there’s lots of ways of doing it! Now I feel dumb.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers already given it is worth noting, that you can store pretty much anything in R lists, even functions. So this works as well:

```
funs <- list(log, log10, sqrt)
f <- funs[[1]]
2 %>% f
```

Comment: Interesting how you can’t combine the second and third lines, though.

Comment: They can be combined like this: `2 %>% funs[[1]](.)` where the dot is optional.

Comment: Ah, of course - for the same reason as mentioned in the other answer above. Thanks.